# Can questions be asked on more than one Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, questions, policy, cross-posting

No one likes duplicate questions, but I'm considering posting a question about information theory. It would be well-suited to both Cross Validated AND [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). I'd be interested in the opinions of both communities. Can a single question be shared across two (or more) Stack Exchange sites? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: I actually kinda like duplicate questions...especially when they're altered slightly to suit their respective sites, and acknowledge one another explicitly. Also, I like to point to [this answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/246931) ([no longer MSO!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/246931)) when there's a question worth cross-posting. The tactics there worked for me ([more or less](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11283/6389))!

Comment: I actually much like duplicate questions... especially when different talented people hang out at different sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "cross-posting".  It is a little bit ambiguous, but the general consensus is that it is inappropriate.  This topic has been discussed before on meta.CV; see these threads:

- [Is the help 'misinformed' on the question of cross-posting?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1880/7290),
- [Cross-posting in CV and math.SE tends to become an epidemic](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1948/7290), and
- [Posting the same question on other statistics forums in addition to CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/941/7290).

Your situation may be different, though.  The typical problem is that someone asks an identical statistics question here and on math.SE (which has a `[statistics]` tag and small set of dedicated followers), or an R / statistics question here and on SO. Your description is too vague for me to know for sure, but I wonder if the statistical and cryptographical aspects are different aspects of the question.  If you want a statistical perspective on something, and a cryptographical perspective on it as well, that strikes me as acceptable.  You aren't just fishing for a faster answer, or trying to find someone who'll do your homework for you, and the answers wouldn't provide duplicate information across the SE system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The specific question I had in mind is somewhat beside the point, I wanted to learn the proper protocol here. Anyway my question was on the use of entropy in information theory to find the information gained though a process. On the face of it it looks like a purely CV question, but the more I read into it the more it seemed the specific uses of information gain are applied to cryptography! Again, thanks for your complete answer!